# Has the new Password Visibility Toggle broken existing drawableRight for EditTexts?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-support-library, android-drawable, android-textinputlayout

**EDIT** I just tried an `EditText` without a `TextInputLayout` and it works as expected. So the problem must be with new changes in the `TextInputLayout`.

I have been using a custom `EditText` class as child of a `TextInputLayout` for around a month. When the user typed, an `x` would appear in the `drawableRight` field. I have successfully displayed images for `drawableLeft`, `drawableTop`, and `drawableBottom`, but setting `drawableRight` provides me with a blank. **Note:** Clicking the blank space where the `X` SHOULD be works as expected, the text is cleared.

This first picture is how it originally looked:

[image]

Ever since upgrading to `support-v4:24.2.0` the functionality has been broken. It now places the "x" where a drawable set with `drawableBottom` should appear. This second picture shows the new behavior:

[image]

### XML Code

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_delivery_info_state"
            android:hint="@string/state_hint"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/large_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/large_margin">
            <com.example.ui.edittexts.ClearableEditText
                android:id="@+id/et_state"
                android:inputType="textCapWords|text|textNoSuggestions"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/et_di_zip_code"
                android:text="@={deliveryViewModel.state}"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

### Java

```
    final Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_clear_text_gray_x);
    final Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
    mClearTextIcon.setBounds(0, 0, mClearTextIcon.getIntrinsicWidth(), mClearTextIcon.getIntrinsicHeight());
    mClearTextIcon.setVisible(true, false);
    final Drawable[] compoundDrawables = getCompoundDrawables();
    setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
            compoundDrawables[0],
            compoundDrawables[1],
            visible ? mClearTextIcon : null,
            compoundDrawables[3]);
```

Comment: Same here, but we are not the only ones having this problem: [Issue 220728](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220728&can=1&q=textinputlayout&sort=-opened&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened) and [Issue 220572](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220572&can=1&q=textinputlayout&sort=-opened&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## UPDATE 14 SEP 2016

A new version of support library `24.2.1` is out and this issue is marked as fixed. According to changelog

> Fixed issues:
>
> TextInputLayout overrides right compound drawable. (AOSP issue 220728)

### Original answer

**Warning 1**
This answer will break this new password visibility toggle feature.

**Warning 2**
This answer may cause an unexpected behaviour after updating support lib (assuming that they will fix this issue).

Looks like `TextInputLayout` screws things up here, specifically these lines from `updatePasswordToggleView` method.

```
final Drawable[] compounds = TextViewCompat.getCompoundDrawablesRelative(mEditText);
TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawablesRelative(mEditText, compounds[0], compounds[1], mPasswordToggleDummyDrawable, compounds[2]);
```

As you can see it sets `mPasswordToggleDummyDrawable` as a `right` drawable and then sets `compounds[2]` (which is your custom drawable that you want to be one the right) as a `bottom` drawable.

`updatePasswordToggleView` method is called in `onMeasure` method. Possible workaround is to create a custom `TextInputEditText` and override  it's `onMeasure` method. Let's call it `PassFixTextInputEditText`

```
public class PassFixTextInputEditText extends TextInputEditText {

    public PassFixTextInputEditText(final Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public PassFixTextInputEditText(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public PassFixTextInputEditText(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        Drawable[] drawables = getCompoundDrawables();
        setCompoundDrawables(drawables[0], drawables[1], drawables[3], null);
    }
}
```

and use it like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:errorEnabled="true">

    <com.kamilzych.temp.PassFixTextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/textInputEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="23"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

(don't forget to change the package name)

As you can see, after `TextInputLayout` sets your custom drawable as bottom drawable we set it as a right one.

Comment: Great answer. I've been advocating the clearable option on edit text views for a while so I was bit upset to see that the support library broke it with the latest one. It looks like when you override the on measure in the ClearableEditText that you should call the super *after* you set the compound drawables - otherwise it allows space for the drawable that has now moved from bottom to right.

Comment: Any idea how they added the Hotspot/selectableItemBackground on the password icon btw - it strikes me that would also be useful on the 'x' icon.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I wish SO would notify me that you had updated I just came back across this by chance.

Comment: it should be also noted that the behavior of `TextViewCompat. setCompoundDrawablesRelative()` is important here, if you were previously using `textView.setCompoundDrawables()` it appears not to work and you have to use the `relative` version