# NullPointerException on TextInputLayout.passwordVisibilityToggleRequested

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-textinputlayout, android-support-design, android-textinputedittext

I got an error in Firebase crash reporting about `Password toggle button` on an app in release mode in some real devices. The problem is the stack trace error is all about `android.support.design` code like you will see in the following log taken from firebase console:

> **Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference**
> android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawable.isStarted (AnimatedVectorDrawable.java:427)
>   android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawable.start (AnimatedVectorDrawable.java:440)
>   android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawable$AnimatedVectorDrawableTransition.start (AnimatedStateListDrawable.java:339)
>   android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawable.selectTransition (AnimatedStateListDrawable.java:226)
>   android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawable.onStateChange (AnimatedStateListDrawable.java:145)
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setState (Drawable.java:599)
>   android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapperGingerbread.setState (DrawableWrapperGingerbread.java:145)
>   android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapperLollipop.setState (DrawableWrapperLollipop.java:95)
>   android.widget.ImageView.drawableStateChanged (ImageView.java:1115)
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.drawableStateChanged (AppCompatImageButton.java:149)
>   android.view.View.refreshDrawableState (View.java:16052)
>   android.support.design.widget.CheckableImageButton.setChecked (CheckableImageButton.java:75)
>   **android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.passwordVisibilityToggleRequested (TextInputLayout.java:1293)**
>   android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout$4.onClick (TextInputLayout.java:1074)
>   android.view.View.performClick (View.java:4785)
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:19888)
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
>   android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:135)
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5276)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:911)
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:706)

I have been tracking some errors related to this widget before, I mean, I post [this question related to password toggle visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41433764/1332549) and I had found some question about this component:

- [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39132192/1332549)
- [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41383424/1332549)

Also I found some AOSP issues about it:

- [this was been fixed in 25.1.1](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230461)
- [this one was closed without get fixed :S](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=227917)

Now I'm getting this error that **I guess is happening when the user just press the toggle button**

It's happening in the following real devices:
[image: devices reported by firebase crash]

The XML about the TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText and its theme:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/login_field_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/perfil_field_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:maxLength="100"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            android:paddingEnd="5dp"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <!--//hint color And Label Color in False State-->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <!--<item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>-->
    <!--//Label color in True State And Bar Color False And True State-->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Like I said at beginning, it's `toggle button` code from support library and it smells like a bug.
**Questions**

- Is there some work around or what I'm doing wrong? (disabling that button is not an option)
- How can I report this to AOSP if I don't have enough "steps" to reproduce it, I just have what Firebase crash console gave me.

Comment: What I'm primarily seeing is the NullPointerException, that is thrown  presumably when a not initilizised ArrayList get's its method size() been called. Do you know, where this is happening?

Comment: In my code, I have a fragment with 2 TextInputEditText like the one in the question and a button for login process. But the NullPointer is raised when the user touch the toggle button. As far as I can see it's happening inside TextInputEditText's password toggle button.

Comment: Yeah, you maybe right hten.

Comment: by the way, the password toggle button has a bug [that has not been fixed and they closed it in AOSP like I said in the question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41433764/1332549)